# linux show process duration

Tags: linux

how do I show how long it takes to run a command on linux? eg

```
gunzip large.gz
```

and I want to show how long it took.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, `$ time gunzip large.gz` will tell you how long `$ gunzip large.gz` takes.

You can also watch the process while it's executing using `top` or `ps`.

Answer (score 1):

Although one can always use `$ time (command)`, I prefer using the method which would spit out the time even when the process is running. To do that, there is one simple way:

```
$ ps -p ?? -o etime
```

Where `??` is the pid of the running process. This will give the exact time elapsed since the start of the process.